# Can't fill bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and am trying to fill an array in a shell script so that I can loop over it and utilize its contents to fill a text file.  However, there's a snag: it doesn't seem to be filling.

I've simplified the larger script that I'm working with down to the essential issue, reprinted below:

```
WL_START=1
WL_END=5
WL_INC=1
wl_range=$(seq $WL_START $WL_INC $WL_END)

declare -a WL

for i in $wl_range # loop through sequence and fill array
do
    WL[$i]=${wl_range[$i]}
done

echo $wl_range
echo ${wl_range[1]}
echo $WL
echo ${WL[1]}
```

However, my output looks like this:

1 2 3 4 5

empty line

empty line

empty line

Any ideas?  I know that people say to just use seq to fill the array, but I had the same problem there as well.

Comment: `wl_range` is not an array; it's a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much work.

```
WL=($(seq $WL_START $WL_INC $WL_END))
```

Comment: I already tried using seq, but did not know to add the parens outside of the $(seq ...) statement.  Editing that and echoing out the individual elements appears to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`wl_range` is a string consisting of space-delimited numbers, not an array. Your `for` loop should simply look like

```
for i in $wl_range; do
  WL[i]=$i
done
```

That said, don't use the `for` loop; use @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams' answer.